# R lyapunov exponent of a system

Tags: r, exponent

I would like to calculate the maximal Lyapunov exponent of a dynamical system, using R. I have to calculate based on the data (time series). 
I have checked the packages tSeriesChaos, fNonLinear (it is the same) and nonlinearTseries. These packages have the functions tSeriesChaos::lyap_k and nonlinearTseries::maxLyapunov.

All of them state that the time series has to be univariate. However, I would like to reconstruct the system using various time series instead of embedding a single one. 
Actually, I have used a multivariate time series as input of the functions mentioned above and it worked; however, I don't know if the results are fine because in theory the time series should be univariate (as stated in the functions help).
So, my questions are:
* Do these functions admit multivariate time series or not?
* Is there any R package that can do this?

I do not think my questions require to provide any code, but I will if you wish.

I tried also RTisean. The package does not work (it lacks a namespace) and some functions gave errors when I sourced them without packaging. Despite this, I could estimate the exponent, however I am reluctant to trust the package because it seems that it is not completed.

Thank you in advance

Marina

Answer (score 0):

The package GPoM.FDLyapu, which did not exist when I asked this question, can be used.